# Lazy loading image component not updated when is in the view port

Tags: ember.js, components, lazy-loading, viewport

I created a component that will load itself when it is in the viewport. The problem that I am facing is that it is not updating itself once it is in the viewport. The ​mixing job is only way to check if the component is in the view port or not. As for now this is ONLY working every time I refresh the page. I would like the component to be updated when the user scrolls down instead of refreshing. Would appreciate if someone could set me on the right path.
**Mixin**:

```
​App.InViewportMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    enteredViewport: function(){
       var win = $(window);

        var viewport = {
            top : win.scrollTop(),
            left : win.scrollLeft()
        };

        viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
        viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

        var bounds = this.$().offset();
        bounds.right = bounds.left + this.$().outerWidth();
        bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.$().outerHeight();

        return (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right  || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));
    }.property(),
});
```

**Component:**

```
​App.LazyImageComponent = Ember.Component.extend(App.InViewportMixin,{
    loadComponent: function() {
        var enteredViewport = this.get('enteredViewport');
        if (enteredViewport == true) {
             console.log(enteredViewport);
        }
    }.observes("enteredViewport").on('didInsertElement')
});
```

**Template:**

{{lazy-image}}

Comment: Have you looked at what others have done? Consider using the ember-in-viewport addon. https://github.com/dockyard/ember-in-viewport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are some issues with your computed properties. You are specifying it as `property()` without specifying any dependent properties. So your CP will only be calculated once and the rest of the times the cached results are returned.

Now you have not done anything to listen to a scroll event. You will need add a listener to recompute your property.

I have made some modifications to your code. [Here is the working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/giwomo/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
App.InViewportMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
  windowInstance: null,

  //Setting to null instead of false to trigger when first value is set
  enteredViewport: null, 

  calcViewport: function(win,top, left){
    var viewport = {
      top : top,
      left : left
    };

    viewport.right = viewport.left + win.width();
    viewport.bottom = viewport.top + win.height();

    var bounds = this.$().offset();
    bounds.right = bounds.left + this.$().outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + this.$().outerHeight();

    var inViewport =  (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right  || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom));

    this.set('enteredViewport', inViewport); 
  },

  scrolled: function() {
    var win = this.get('windowInstance');
    this.get('calcViewport').call(this, win, win.scrollTop(), win.scrollLeft());
  },

  setupScrollListener: function() {
    this.set('windowInstance', $(window));

    //Fire off firstime before any scroll.
    this.get('scrolled').call(this);

    Em.$(window).scroll(this.get('scrolled').bind(this));
  }.on('didInsertElement'),
});

App.LazyImageComponent = Ember.Component.extend(App.InViewportMixin, {
    loadComponent: function() {
        var enteredViewport = this.get('enteredViewport');
        console.log(enteredViewport);
    }.observes("enteredViewport")
});
```

I have just setup  a scroll listener on `didInsertElement` that will trigger a `scroll` handler. This handler will compute if the element is in viewport and set the value to 'enteredViewport'. The `scroll` handler is invoked on `didInsertElement` for initial computing of the property before any scroll events triggger.

But do checkout the addon mentioned in the comment. Might be done in a better way.